# C# WPF accented characters showing as question mark

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm attempting to write a simple translator class.

This class will convert a json string to a JObject and return values based on a key and a language.

My problem is that there is some encoding issue that I am having trouble figuring out how to solve. Here is my class

```
namespace XCheck.Classes.Utilities {
    static class Translator {

        public static string Get(string key, string language) {
            JObject lang = JObject.Parse(ReadResource("XCheck.Properties.lang.json"));
            return (string)lang[key][language];
        }

        public static string ReadResource(string name) {
            // Determine path
            var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            string resourcePath = name;

            using(Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourcePath))
            using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream)) {
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Here is my JSON file

```
{
  "XCVersion": {
    "english": "XC Version",
    "spanish": "Versión XC"
  }
}
```

When my app runs, and I use the spanish version of the string, it prints the accented character as a question mark.

This is how I set the string in the UI.

```
parent.topPanelVersionText.Text = $"{Translator.Get("XCVersion", "spanish")}: {version.Major}.{version.Minor}";
```

How can I make the character show properly?

When I add the text directly to the element via XAML, it displays properly.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="topPanelVersionText" Text="Versión XC: 1.0 " TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Uniform" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Normal"/>
```

[image]

Comment: This may just be a FONT issue.  You need to use a Font that contains the character.

Comment: @jdweng When I add the text directly to the element inside XAML, it displays fine with the font I am using.

Comment: Could also be an encoding issue.is the JSON file UTF8 encoded?

Comment: @KlausGütter I'm not sure. How can I check this? I created the file by right clicking the Properties folder in the `Solution Explorer -> Add -> New Item -> JSON file`

Comment: E.g. using and editor like Notepad++ where you can seelct the encoding to be used. Or if everything else failed by looking with a binary editor. The ó should be 0xC3 0xB3 in UTF8.

Comment: A character in Net is a two byte class with a private property indicating if the character is one or two bytes.  One bytes characters have standard values ofr 0x00 to 0x7F,  The bytes 0x80 to 0xFF are single bytes values that are mapped to unicode (two bytes) depending on the encoding.  This is done so a character can be represented in one byte to save memory.  The questionis when you pasted the character into XAML did you paste a two byte unicode character (no encoding needed) or a one byte character.  I suspect you pasted the two byte character.

Comment: @jdweng Possibly, I just copied it directly from the json file.

Comment: @KlausGütter It looks to be saved as ANSI. If I change it to UTF-8, and edit the file inside Visual Studio, will that encoding stay the same?

Comment: I would go to word or excel and Insert a character from a Font that is not unicode.  Then paste the character into xaml and see what happens.

Comment: You can get character like this : string d3 = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252").GetString(new byte[] { 0xd3 });

Comment: @jdweng "A character in Net is a two byte class with a private property indicating if the character is one or two bytes" - that is wrong. A [char}(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char) in .NET is always two bytes in UTF16 encoding. What you descibe if the representation of a code point in UTF8.

Comment: @KlausGütter : That link says "shows SOME of he methods" and shows sample of code.  Not what is inside the Net dll.

Comment: @jdweng That link says "Represents a character *as a UTF-16 code unit*"

Comment: @KlausGütter :  I said two bytes which is 16 bits.

Comment: @jdweng I was referring to your claim "indicating if the character is one or two bytes"